# CSS remove text below an image

Tags: html, css

How to align the the p tag just below the user name and not below the image without using padding/margin-left.

code:

```
<ul class="comments_list">
  <li>
      <i>
        <img src='{{image_path}}' />
      </i>
      <span>User name</span>
      <p>{{comment_text}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your question, it's somewhat unclear to me what you're exactly trying to accomplish. It'd be nice if you showed an example of your problem, in the form of a JSfiddle or website.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do? What is your css for 'class="comments_list"'
Are you using `<i>` for italics??

```html
<ul class="comments_list">
  <li>
      <i>
        <img src=http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dryicons/simplistica/128/user-icon.png />
      </i>
       </li>
      </ul>
<span>User name</span>
      <p>{{comment_text}}</p>
```

Comment: The span is next to the image because they are both inline. The p is a new line and i want it to be below the span and not below to the image

Answer (score 0):

if you do not mind using flex, it makes things easy to do: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mPQeRM

```css
li {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 128px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="comments_list">
  <li>
    <i>
        <img src=http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dryicons/simplistica/128/user-icon.png />
      </i>
    <span>User name</span>
    <p>{{comment_text}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```